# The roots of the cubic equation $z^3-2z^2+pz+10=0$ are $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Show that $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=p+13$

Tags: roots, cubics

$$z^3-2z^2+pz+10=0$$
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a=1,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, b=-2,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, c=p,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, d=10$$

$$(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)$$
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-\frac{b}{a}$$
$$\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=\frac{c}{a}$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,(-\frac{b}{a})^2-2(\frac{c}{a})$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,(-\frac{(-2)}{(1)})^2-2(\frac{(p)}{(1)})$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,4-2p$$

This is the only method I know.

Edit: Extra information if needed. $$\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3=-4$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the roots of the equation, we have
$$\begin{align}\alpha^3-2\alpha^2+p\alpha+10=0\\
\beta^3-2\beta^2+p\beta+10=0\\
\gamma^3-2\gamma^2+p\gamma+10=0\end{align}$$
Add all three equations and rearrange
$$\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{2}p+\frac{\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3}{2}+15$$
Given the information already outlined in your question, I reckon you can take it from here.

Comment: Wow, I find it quite amazing that you can just add equations together like this. Feels like it breaks so many rules... but I got $p+13$!

Comment: Although it may feel like it breaks so many rules, it is quite legitimate. As $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are roots of polynomial $f(x)$, we have $f(\alpha)=0$, $f(\beta)=0$ and $f(\gamma)=0$, which implies that $f(\alpha)+f(\beta)+f(\gamma)=0$, which you can then rearrange.

Comment: If for example $f(\alpha)=2$, $f(\beta)=3$ and $f(\gamma)=5$ could you still add them together as long as you added up the RHS too? $f(\alpha)+f(\beta)+f(\gamma)=2+3+5$

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth Yes, you are right. You add all the LHS terms, and keep the  sum on the LHS, then you add all the RHS terms and keep the sum on the RHS. Once you have done this, you can rearrange the resulting equation to your hearts content.